# Looking for a specific story of a pen-tester who used a fake raffle to get a keylogger into a company

Tags: penetration-test, keyloggers, social-engineering

While reading about USB hardware keyloggers on the web a few months ago, I stumbled upon a story by a rather patient pen-tester:

> He organized a raffle where the first prize was a cool gamer keyboard — with an implaneted hardware keylogger. :-) And of course he sent invitations for this raffle only to a very few selected target persons (IT admins) inside the target company. And as the organizer of the raffle he could decide himself which administrator will win that cool keyboard.
>
> That way he got the keylogger into the company and it worked quite well for a while. But suddenly the keylogger recorded rather different usage patterns and not stuff the winner of the raffle would do. In the end the keyboard was so cool that it caused envy with coworkers of that admin, so that when the admin was on holidays, one of his coworkers grabbed the keyboard and used it for a few weeks.

Unfortunately I haven't bookmarked where that story has been posted and now I want to reference to it in an article I'm writing and can't find it anymore on the web. :-(

I searched for quite some keyword combinations on Duckduckgo and Startpage (i.e. Google). But even after trying to find that article on the web again every few days for a few weeks, I wasn't able to find it anymore.

Things I unfortunately can't remember anymore about the story:

- If the term "raffle" was used or if another term like "prize", "contest" or "competition" was used.
- If the article in English or in German. (Although English is more likely.)
- Which of terms "pen-test", "pen-tester", "pen-testing", "penetration test", "penetration tester" or "penetration testing" was used. (I hoped the search engine will consider them equal, but given my luck I suspect they don't.)
- If the used hardware keylogger was sending out his results (e.g. over wireless) regularily or if its content has been retrieved at a single point in time later.

Things I vaguely remember:

- The article was written from a first-person perspective.
- The pen-tester was hired by the company to try to break in (probably electronically). IIRC the company's name was not mentioned.
- The pen-tester had quite a lot of time to find a way into the company: several weeks or even a few months.
- The pen-tester was more or less aware that the admin is keen on the keyboard used as prize, i.e. he did some social-engineering in advance to that raffle.
- It might have been a blog posting and I very likely read it on a HTML page and not in a PDF document.
- The used keyboard was a rather pricy one, like $150 or $200.

So I'd be really happy if anyone remembers that article better than I do and either knows more specific details about it (to refine my web search) or even knows where to find that article.

Comment: I remember reading it too. Forgot where though. Could have been on imgur or reddit?

Comment: @Joakim: No, IIRC it was neither on a forum-style page (but I'm not 100% sure) nor inside an image. (I'm quite sure about the latter and AFAIK imgur is only for image hosting.)

Comment: After thinking some more..: could it have been a Defcon youtube video?

Comment: @Joakim: Thanks for the suggestion, but nope: I'm very sure that I _read_ the story.

Comment: @AxelBeckert did you check your browser history?

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction: A very good idea, but unfortunately I restarted the browser multiple times since then and I configured it to not save the history across restarts. What I though did is to look through all open tabs (programmatically) to see if it's still open. I'll also grep through the browser cache on disk to see if I find something. So thanks for that direction of ideas.

Comment: So, this book mentions an attack vector just like this, but does not reference a specific case of doing so: https://books.google.com/books?id=avWcBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=penetration+tester+case+study+contest+keyboard&source=bl&ots=yA4P-VdNUq&sig=wKEQ39KfOr05s8WJMrG1Dy054fA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEtYCuiKfSAhVD1CYKHXCOD5wQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=penetration%20tester%20case%20study%20contest%20keyboard&f=false

Comment: Here's a similar attack vector using a mouse: http://web.archive.org/web/20110628232208/http://pentest.snosoft.com/2011/06/24/netragards-hacker-interface-device-hid

Comment: @Joe: Thanks! Both are interesting attacks and the book refers to http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/programmable-hid-usb-keystroke-dongle which I also had read a few weeks ago. But both cases involve the Teensy board which emulates a keyboard typing programmatically. The attack vector involved a key _logger_ which doesn't seem to be used here.

Comment: Gna. If I now [search for _usb keyboard perimenter keylogger raffle_ on Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=usb+keyboard+perimeter+keylogger+raffle&kk=-1&ia=web) I get this question as first hit already. Not helping! ;-)

Comment: can't find it, but upvote for the interesting story lol

Comment: Closed as "off-topic" after 7 years? Seriously?!?